# Devuelve error al instalar un paquete npm

Tags: reactjs, npm

Quiero instalar un componente llamado Material-ui/Core en React pero me lanza muchos errores.

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/react npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
> npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@material-ui/core npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from
> the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency
> conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or
> --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\LuisErnestoUriasChav\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt
> for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Luis\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-01T16_29_54_939Z-debug-0.log

Y uso este comando para instalarlo... aun que ya he probado varios y nada.

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el error te está diciendo que el `react` que tiene como dependencia es  `peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0"` y tu `react` actual `eact@18.2.0`

Actualmente el paquete incluso cambió de nombre, entonces intenta con

```
npm install @mui/material --legacy-peer-deps
```

o

```
npm install @mui/material --force
```

Básicamente la primer opción ignora las `peerDependencies` que son las que causan tu error, y la segunda opción lo fuerza a hacerlo.

Ten en cuenta que esto puede llegar a ocasionar a que los elementos de las librería puedan no tener el comportamiento esperado, dado que están diseñados muchas veces a trabajar con esas versiones específicas.